# news site for a complete beginner

Tags: emails

I'm a programmer with medium skills in Java-C# with few knowledge about web development. Now I want to create a news site for our corporation.

I searched a bit and found that Drupal is a good tool to create a news site but I don't know if I can do this or not.
Currently I know nothing about PHP and Drupal.

So my questions are

- Is it possible to create, manage and maintain a small news site using Drupal without (or with few) PHP skills?
- If Drupal is not a good choice, what other options I have?

Comment: Asking *"Is it possible to create, manage and maintain a small news site using Drupal without (or with few) PHP skills?"* is like asking *"Is it possible to get a car that will meet my needs exactly, without paying for customizations?"*. How can we know? We don't know your needs. Also, Help Center forbids comparisons with other CMS here. We don't want a flame wars.

Comment: The short answers are "yes" and "yes".  However, this is going to be closed as off-topic.  A place where these questions are on-topic is the forum [Before you start](https://drupal.org/forum/20) at Drupal.org.  I suggest you try there.

Comment: Of course if you have a *specific* feature in mind, and you want to ask if / how Drupal supports it, or how can it be implemented, feel free to ask us here. Just make sure it's not something that can be found via 5 minutes of search with popular search engine ;) and that your need is described pretty clearly. Help Center says this site is for people *using or thinking about using the Drupal CMS*, so we will not kick you out just because you are only thinking now, but we will expect more own effort and precision in asking than forum suggested by @GisleHannemyr.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help and clarification on the subject, even when the question doesn't meet the forum's standards.

Comment: @mohsenof This site is **not a forum**, that's pretty much the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Drupal is a good choice to get started.. You can create and maintain site without PHP knowledge using Drupal since your requirements is very simple and can be achieved using out of the box Drupal.

You can try using [OpenPublish](https://drupal.org/project/openpublish) Distro..

> OpenPublish is a packaged distribution designed for the online news
>   industry. It is ideal for the implementation of a variety of media
>   outlets sites including magazines, newspapers, journals, trade
>   publications, broadcast, wire service, multimedia sites and membership
>   publications. OpenPublish is built for flexibility, customization, and
>   extension -- a powerful CMS to help publishers focus on their content.